# transaction in notification but not in transactions

Tags: transactions

I just processed a test transaction, everything went well. I can see the transaction under sandbox notifications but when I click on sandbox transactions and choose the right email I don't see anything. Shouldn't I immediately see it?

Comment: Hi @Ursula_pdx! Welcome to SO! 
Transaction of what?

Comment: I did express checkout to buy something. I expect that when I go to my paypal developer sandbox and look into the account where supposedly the transaction happened, that I would see that transaction but I don't see it. However, If I click on notifications I can see that it did indeed happened. So, my question is why my purchase does not show in the transactions area?